# How to call native android code from a page served using nanohttpd server?

Tags: android, native, web-frontend, nanohttpd

I wish to create a web interface for my android application wherein the user can connect using WiFi and do "stuff" similar to the web interfaces provided by many file sharing services like Xender.

[image: Xender Web interface]

I am using nanohttpd to host the web interface. I wish to call a function when a user presses a button on the web page (for example to turn on the flash light).

When the application is opened it starts the server and listens on a particular port. The web interface basically consists of a button. A user can log into the web interface and press the button to turn on the flash light. For that I need the android code to be called when the user presses the button.

How can I accomplish this? Are there better alternatives?

Comment: So the page ( static or dynamic? ) is served by nanohttpd. And who is displaying it? And where? You should tell much more of your setup.

Comment: @greenapps I have updated the question details. I am not sure how to implement this. But the requirement is similar to the web interface provided by file sharing applications like Xender.

Comment: I do not know Xender. You did not answer my question who is displaying the web page.And other questions. Your description is still very vague and confusing. For instance: `When the application is opened it starts the server and listens on a particular port`. You mean that your app will start nanohttpd? Ok. And your app listens on a specific port? Is your app a server too? For what?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is late but adding in case someone reach to this page and still looking for the answer.
If a browser would be used to access the web page from nanoHttpd server there is no easy way to call the native APIs as mentioned in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614987/accessing-android-api-from-browser?answertab=active#tab-top).
Instead a web view can be used to render the page and then the native APIs can be used using addJavascriptInterface as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript).
Also frameworks like [PhoneGap](https://phonegap.com/) or [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) can be used to get the specific functionality already built in as a plugin to use. Check this PhoneGap plugin for flashlight [here](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Flashlight-PhoneGap-Plugin/tree/6d0889313534b6357c34a1fb458a57dd837929ce).
Although if opening page in a browser is a requirement, you can also use [Android Intents with chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) to launch a service application which will call the required native APIs.