# How to Interact with Java forms elements without Java Access Bridge?

Tags: javascript, java

I need to know if exist another way to interact with Java Forms Elements Without using Java Access Bridge.   Im going to explain...  I using a system builded in Java Forms, and I need to attach this process, like the chromeDrive do, and interact with elements like buttons, textbox, checkbox...  Im thinking about Java x javascript, but how I attach java process for manipulation in Javascript

Somebody knows any solutions to this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [accessing Android API from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614987/accessing-android-api-from-browser)